# How to bind rows without losing those with character(0)?

Tags: r, rbind

I have a list like `L` (comes from a vector splitting).

```
L <- strsplit(c("1 5 9", "", "3 7 11", ""), " ")

# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "5" "9"
# 
# [[2]]
# character(0)
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "3"  "7"  "11"
# 
# [[4]]
# character(0)
```

When I do an ordinary `rbind` as follows, I'm losing all the `character(0)` rows.

```
do.call(rbind, L)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "1"  "5"  "9" 
# [2,] "3"  "7"  "11"
```

Do I always have to do a `lapply` like the following or have I missed something?

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(L, function(x) 
    if (length(x) == 0)  rep("", 3) else x))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "1"  "5"  "9" 
# [2,] ""   ""   ""  
# [3,] "3"  "7"  "11"
# [4,] ""   ""   ""
```

Base R answers are preferred.

Comment: How about "recoding" the `""` to something else then `rbind` followed by replacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `lapply` you don't have to worry about length so you can skip the `rep` part it will automatically be recycled across columns.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(L, function(x) if (length(x) == 0)  "" else x))

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "1"  "5"  "9" 
#[2,] ""   ""   ""  
#[3,] "3"  "7"  "11"
#[4,] ""   ""   ""
```

---

Another option using same logic as @NelsonGon we can replace the empty lists with blank and then `rbind`.

```
L[lengths(L) == 0] <- ""
do.call(rbind, L)

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "1"  "5"  "9" 
#[2,] ""   ""   ""  
#[3,] "3"  "7"  "11"
#[4,] ""   ""   ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this roundabout using data.table suits you:

```
L <- data.table::tstrsplit(c("1 5 9", "", "3 7 11", ""), " ", fill="")
t(do.call(rbind,L))
```

Answer (score 2):

**With `plyr`** then proceed with replacement. Since OP asked for base R, see below.

```
 plyr::ldply(L,rbind)
     1    2    3
1    1    5    9
2 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3    3    7   11
4 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

A less efficient base R way:

```
 L <- strsplit(c("1 5 9", "", "3 7 11", ""), " ")
 L[lapply(L,length)==0]<-"Miss"
 res<-Reduce(rbind,L)
 res[res=="Miss"]<-""
```

Result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
init "1"  "5"  "9" 
     ""   ""   ""  
     "3"  "7"  "11"
     ""   ""   ""
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the defined behavior for scenarios like that. As written in `?rbind`:

> For cbind (rbind), vectors of zero length (including NULL) are ignored
>   unless the result would have zero rows (columns), for S compatibility.
>   (Zero-extent matrices do not occur in S3 and are not ignored in R.)

When you inspect your elements, you see that it is true:

```
length(L[[1]])

[1] 3

length(L[[2]])

[1] 0
```

However, as you see, multiple workarounds are possible.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stri_list2matrix` in a simple way

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(L, byrow = TRUE, fill = "")
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "1"  "5"  "9" 
#[2,] ""   ""   ""  
#[3,] "3"  "7"  "11"
#[4,] ""   ""   ""
```